# 2 defaulted copy constructors: is it possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, default, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

Is the following program ill-formed?

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(Foo&) = default;

    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
};

int main() 
{
}
```

It successfully [compiles with *clang++ 3.8.0* and *g++ 6.3.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5624219a11734b4b) (compiler flags are `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`).

Comment: Um.. These are not *default* copy constructors. These are *default**ed*** copy constructors. Other than that they are no different from copy constructors defined in regular fashion (with `{}`). There's nothing unusual in having two copy constructors with different const-qualifications on the parameter.

Comment: @AnT I'm sorry for my bad English. Default**ed**, of course.

Comment: `Foo(Foo&)` is (also) a valid copy constructor.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I know. My question is about having two defaulted copy constructors (with different signatures) simultaneously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why should this be ill-formed? You define two copy constructors, one which expects a non-const argument and the other which can use a const argument. You then tell the compiler it should use its default implementation for these two constructors. Unless the compiler has a reason to eliminate the default copy constructors, you could also delete those two lines and would get the same result. Also I think the first version is redundant, since the default implementation should anyway be fine with a const argument. Still defining both is legal, since you might want to do something different in the two cases.